# How do i hide the tables created in visual studio 2010 C#?

Tags: c#

How do i hide the tables created in visual studio 2010 C#? What i am trying to do is to hide the table (somewhat like timetable) and only let it appear when user click on one of the calendar dates. I tried using Visibility: hidden; but the whole table disappeared when i view on the design view. I need help! Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you set `Visibility: hidden;` you can't see that element in design view, but you could write some code in JavaScript to change that table's visibility at tun time then it'll be visible at runtime to you, or just make table visible if you want to do some editing in that, Further more you still have the Source view where you can do editing in that table's UI if you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear, but from what I understood, this is how you can achieve:

In the codebehind (C# .cs file) you can set the table as hidden using the style property, something like this:

.aspx file

```
<table id="table1" runat="server">
......td's and tr's.....    
</table>
```

.cs file in `Page_Load`

```
table1.Style.Add("display", "none");
```

This will allow you to see the table in design mode, and when the page is rendered on client's browser `Table` will be hidden.

***Note**: You cannot use `this.table1.Visible = false;` in codebehind to hide the table because in this case table will never reach the client-side browser and you wont be able to show the table at all, so you should use `table1.Style.Add("display", "none");` if you want to send the table to client's browser in hidden mode.*

You can use JQuery or Javascript on the client side to show the table.

So when a user clicks on a calendar date you call a javascript function. This javascript function will get the **Table** object from **DOM** by Id or class and show it by setting `Style display` to `block`

Comment: Please see the code I have added to my post, hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear explanation. The function that i am implementing is the Appointment booking whereby my tables consists of Start Time and End Time and various days (from monday to sunday). Users are allowed to click on the buttons created in the table to select their ideal timings for appointment. Therefore, when the user first sees the page, they are not suppose to see the table. It can only be seen after they have selected the date of the appointment. I hope you understand this better and ThankYou for helping me.

Comment: ThankYou, i have successfully hidden the table but it didnt appear when i click on the calendar. For this, i added an extra code in the Calendar1_SelectionChanged and include table1.Visible = true; but it didnt seems to work. How do i solve this problem?

Comment: okay sure, here is my code:
<code>
public partial class Appointment_BookNewAppointment : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar1.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
        table1.Visible = true;
    }
<code>

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in Calendar1_SelectionChanged, run and see in debug mode if this breakpoint is hit or not.

Comment: i debugged it, it really didnt execute this line: table1.Visible = true; and skip to the next line of codes.

Comment: Have you compiled/build your project after adding this line `table1.visible=true;`? I recommend to stop debugging, then compile/build your project and then run again, see if it works. If this doesn't work then close and restart VS.Net, open your project and run, sometimes this helps. Its difficult to debug until and unless you have the computer in front of you.

Comment: Sure, This is part of my .aspx code
<table id="table1" runat="server" class="style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="style4">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Start Time"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3" width="85">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="End Time"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style3" width="85">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="Monday"></asp:Label>
                    </td>

Comment: This is my .cs code:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        table1.Style.Add("display", "none");
    }
protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToLongDateString();
        Calendar1.Visible = false;
        Label3.Visible = true;
        TextBox2.Visible = true;
        Label4.Visible = true;
        TextBox3.Visible = true;
        table1.Visible = true;
    }

Comment: Some part of aspx code didnt come through, still, based on what I understood from code, you can try adding following C# code in Calendar1_SelectionChanged - `table1.Style["display"] = "block";`. Let me know if it doesnt work.